# Why can't I center with margin: 0 auto?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a `#header` div that is `100% width` and within that div I have an unordered list. I have applied `margin: 0 auto` to the unordered list but it won't center it within the header div.

Can anybody please tell me why? I thought that if I define the width of the parent div, then the unordered list should be able to center itself with `margin: 0 auto`. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  min-height: 160px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#sitename {
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 620px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 35px;
  color: #999;
}

#header ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="header">
    <h1 id="sitename">Photography Auction Site</h1>

    <ul>
      <li>List of Photos</li>
      <li>Image Gallery</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? IE/Win has some problems with Margin auto.

Comment: Why do you also float your ul to the right? Take that out, and probably also the float:left for the li, and you should be fine.

Comment: I am creating a navigation bar. I did take out the float right for the ul and put in a float left for the li, but that puts it all on the left now.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You need to define the width of the element you are centering, not the parent element.

```css
#header ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

*Edit*: Ok, I've seen the testpage now, and here is how I think you want it:

```css
#header ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:90%;
}

/* Remove the float: left; property, it interferes with display: inline and 
 * causes problems. (float: left; makes the element implicitly a block-level
 * element. It is still good to use display: inline on it to overcome a bug
 * in IE6 and below that doubles horizontal margins for floated elements)
 * The styles below is the full style for the list-items. 
 */
#header ul li {
    color:#CCCCCC;
    display:inline;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

Comment: what if the width of the ul will be dynamic. I'm thinking of dynamically putting in different text in the li's with PHP later so I am trying to anticipate that.

Comment: Yup, then you can't center using margin: auto;

Comment: your solution only pushes the ul to the right about 50px. It doesn't center it. Here's the page that I am working on: http://idea-palette.com/test.html

Comment: I tried your latest suggestion, but it didn't work. I have uploaded the newest version with your recommendations to the same location so you can see what I am experiencing. The ul is just being pushed to the right about 50px.

Comment: Like I said in my suggestion, remove the float: left

Comment: That worked GREAT! Thank you sooo very much for sticking with me and helping me out! That problem has been killing me! Thanks again!

Comment: You should be able to center dynamic elements. Responsive elements defined in percentages or ems can be centered with `margin: auto`. The elements just need to be block elements and have some width. I've made `margin: auto` suddenly work by adding a width and/or by adding `display: block`.

Comment: please add "display: block;" if it's inline-block or something else, it doesntwork

Comment: @MichaelMcGinnis I think the dynamic elements referred to by zeckdude are elements whose width is defined by their content. Yes, an element with a percentage width is responsive, but not dynamic in so far that it has a defined width: x %.

Answer (score 57):

An inline-block covers the whole line (from left to right), so a margin left and/or right won't work here. What you need is a block, a block has borders on the left and the right so can be influenced by margins.

This is how it works for me:

```css
#content {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for very useful suggestion, I had the same problem with an inline element and I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working

Comment: This is best answer, and works for multi size window.

Answer (score 15):

Why not?

```css
#header {
    text-align: center;
}

#header ul {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I added text-align: left; to #header ul to center the ul and keep the text in the li aligned to the left. I also needed to set the ul to display as inline-block for the width to be dynamic (auto).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the first answer is the best one, I tried it and not working in fact, as @kalys.osmonov said, you can give `text-align:center` to `header`, but you have to make `ul` as `inline-block` rather than `inline`, and also you have to notice that `text-align` can be inherited which is not good to some degree, so the better way (not working below IE 9) is using `margin` and `transform`. Just remove `float right` and `margin;0 auto` from `ul`, like below:

```
#header ul {
   /* float: right; */
   /* margin: 0 auto; */
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 50%; /* From parent width */
   transform: translateX(-50%); /* use self width which can be unknown */
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); /* For IE9 */
}
```

This way can fix the problem that making dynamic width of `ul` center if you don't care IE8 etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can set the width for ul tag then it will align center.

```
#header ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 420px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to center a div in absolute position. Here, replace `container` with a selector for your container.

```
container { 
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```