# Aligning Div To Middle?

Tags: html

Hello my question is about aligning divs. On a website i am working on for fun i have a div and inside that div is a child div. i need the child to be in the middle of the adult div. The left and right are aligning in the middle but it is stuck to the top. If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ry5xU/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
        </div>
        <div id="content-background">
            <div id="content">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="faqs">
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footer-right">
            </div>
            <div id="footer-left">
            </div>
            <div id="footer-bot">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>






* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#logo {
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

#nav {
    width: 75%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}

#content-background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    clear: both;
    background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
}

#content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#faqs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: red;
}

#footer-right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}

#footer-left {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: pink;
}

#footer-bot {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    clear: both;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Unclear... identify us the exact div need to be aligned

Comment: " have a div and inside that div is a child div." - there are many divs in your code as well as in fiddle. please be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to align the div vertically to the middle as well as horizontally. The child div looks good horizontally, but aligning to the center vertically is a bit trickier.

An easy solution since you know the height of #content-background would be to position #content relative to the parent and then move it down by 150 pixels.

```
#content {
    ...
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ry5xU/3/

Here's a really good breakdown of how you can accomplish true vertical centering:
[How to vertically center divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743989/vertically-aligning-divs)

Comment: "It seems you want to align the div vertically" - how did you concluded which is *the div* to be aligned from question..?

Comment: "The left and right are aligning in the middle but it is stuck to the top." If you look at the attached fiddle, the #content div is aligned center but stuck to the top.

Comment: The question by itself is unclear. the fiddle is just an aid. *Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers*. if the fiddle goes down, then the question is unclear and useless.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `margin:auto` to show a div at center.

Check out [this](http://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/963646/1055241) or [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_container) might help.

Answer (score -1):

```
#main_div {position:relative;}
#child_div {position:absolute; right:50%; margin-right:-200px; top:50%; margin-top:-200px;}
```

you should do this for your css.
when the width and height of your child div is 400px , in "margin-right" or "margin-top" you write -200px on them . It means the half of width with a Minus behind that should be in "margin-right" and the half of height with a Minus behind that should be in "margin-top".
Good luck .

Comment: where is `#main_div` and `#child_div` in the shared code..?

Comment: It's an example. you said a div and inside that a child div.

Comment: Well, then your example is unclear. *you should do this for your css* - adding the the above code won't fix the issue since there are no elements with such `id`s. btw i'm not the op.

Comment: tell me which part of that is unclear that I'll explain it to you.

Comment: *you should do this for your css* - adding the the above code won't fix the issue since there are no elements with such `id`s.