# Why not working margin:0 auto?CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried to align the center of these elements in the contact page.

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=19

```
.contactform11 .wdform_section.{
    /* margin-left:280px; */
    /* margin-top:55px; */
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:auto;       
 }
```

Do not operate this and do not understand why.
I searched the forum and everyone said the information you need to set width and display block.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting a fixed width instead of width:auto. Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963636/why-cant-i-center-with-margin-0-auto

Comment: set width in %, Its working fine for me.. 
.contactform11 .wdform_page {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

Comment: The width of a block element is 100%.  You'll need to set a width lesser than the parent width for an element to center.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML within your question, otherwise this question will be completely worthless once that page you've linked to has been edited.

Comment: You forgot the comma in between the two divs:  .contactform11, .wdform_section. {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block elements have a default width of 100%, so auto margin doesn't make sense.

You can either make it an inline-block element (with a text-align set to center on the parent element), or simply define a specific width.

```css
body {text-align: center;}
div {
  background: #ccf;
  margin: 4px auto;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #99f;
}

#d2 {display: inline-block;}
#d3 {width: 200px;}
```

```html
<div id="d1">Original</div>
<div id="d2">Inline-block</div>
<div id="d3">Specific Width</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Width must be constant for margin to be auto.

Answer (score 0):

in your contact page edit css as

```css
.wdform_page {
  text-align: center;
}
.wdform_section {
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```