# div not in the middle with margin 0 auto?

Tags: html, css

I have a confirm box and I want to show it in the middle of my screen.

`margin 0 auto` does not solve my problem.

How can I center it?

https://jsfiddle.net/y5u5obL0/

```
#confirmBox{
 position:fixed;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:500px;
 height:150px;
 background:#ffffff;
 border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: you can see solution in [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/center-element-with-positionfixed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I center with margin: 0 auto?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963636/why-cant-i-center-with-margin-0-auto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the element is fixed.

You need to add `left: 0;`/`right: 0` in order for the element to be centered (in combination with `margin: 0 auto`). In doing so, the element technically stretches to fill the screen, but since it has a width specified, it will be contained and centered within the available space.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu0fz4ye/)

```
#confirmBox {
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Margin: 0 auto; will not work until you will not provide left:0; and right:0

Comment: @NileshMahajan Why do you say this won't work, and then post the same exact solution *after* me? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I accidentally commented on your answer, actually I was trying to post a comment below the question, your answer is correct .

Comment: sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @NileshMahajan No problem at all.. that comment was just confusing, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to vertically and horizontally center anything, change relative to absolute if you want to remove it from the page flow. Check out the demo to see it in action

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4tcufo5/4/))

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="mycontent">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin: 0 auto; will not work until you will not provide left:0; and right:0

check fiddle for working example :https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/y5u5obL0/1/

**CSS**

```
#confirmBox{
 position:fixed;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:500px;
 height:150px;
 background:#ffffff;
 border:1px solid #ddd;
 left:0; /* Added Property */
 right:0; /* Added Property */
}
```