# Why margin: auto; not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Even though I have added margin: auto; to .content class which is actually the content of the modal, it still positions itself at top left. Why does this happen? How can I centre align it?

```js
var mod=document.getElementById("myModal");
var img= document.getElementById("image");
img.addEventListener("click",animate);
function animate() {
 mod.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#image {
    width: 400px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.modal {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.content {
 margin: auto;
 width: 800px;
 animation-name: zoom;
 animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
@keyframes zoom {
 from {transform: scale(0.1);} 
    to {transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <img id="image" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <img class="content" id="image01" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg">
  </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add this text-align:center for .model class like.. .modal {text-align: center;}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, `<img>` is `replaced inline element` and thus you'll have to convert it to `block`.

Thus, add

```
display: block;
```

too to your CSS for `.content`

That is, the updated CSS for `.content` would be like,

```
.content{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
```

Comment: This is a dupe (must be +100 answers already cover this) so why not vote to close as such?

Comment: Already voted @LGSon..

Comment: @Lal Its clearly copied from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963636/why-cant-i-center-with-margin-0-auto) Don't you think we should close it?

Comment: @Leothelion I've already voted to close the question..

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I'm new to stackoverflow, i didnt know that there must be similar answers. I have not copied the question from anywhere, pls pardon me for not following the rules. It wont happen again

Comment: No issues @DhruvChadha.. Dont be disheartened.. :D

Answer (score 0):

add this text-align:center for .model class like..

```
.modal {text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in css. Which solved your issue seems.

Changed css for content :

```
margin: auto;
display: block;
/* top: 0; */
width: 800px;
animation-name: zoom;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
```

```js
var mod=document.getElementById("myModal");
var img= document.getElementById("image");
img.addEventListener("click",animate);
function animate() {
 mod.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#image {
    width: 400px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.modal {
 display: block;
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
 z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.content {
 margin: auto;
    display: block;  
    width: 800px;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
@keyframes zoom {
 from {transform: scale(0.1);} 
    to {transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <img class="content" id="image01" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg">
  </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>  
 </body>
</html>
```