# Margin wont change for the <div> element

Tags: html, css

I have a  element that I am trying to center using

```
margin = 0 auto;
```

Yet, the margin will not show up when I inspect the page in the browser. Any suggestions of how I could fix this problem?

```css
    #main{
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="main">
      <div id="heading">
        <img class="head" id="mainImg" src="Images/logo.png" alt="Know Music">
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb1">Guitar</button>
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb2">Bass</button>
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb3">Piano</button>
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb4">Drums</button>
        <i class="fa fa-bars menu"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="div-mi1">
        <img id="mi1" alt="Eletric Guitar" src="Images/guitarplaying.jpg">
        <h2 id="mt1" class="font">Test</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963636/why-cant-i-center-with-margin-0-auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to center a `div` with 100% width with margins.  The problem is there is no space for margins when the `div` takes up the entire width.

With a narrower `div`, you'll see the centering take effect.

```css
#main{
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 70%;
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
      <div id="heading">
        <img class="head" id="mainImg" src="Images/logo.png" alt="Know Music">
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb1">Guitar</button>
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb2">Bass</button>
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb3">Piano</button>
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb4">Drums</button>
        <i class="fa fa-bars menu"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="div-mi1">
        <img id="mi1" alt="Eletric Guitar" src="Images/guitarplaying.jpg">
        <h2 id="mt1" class="font">Test</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However, a more robust way of centering is `flexbox`

```css
#main{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
      <div id="heading">
        <img class="head" id="mainImg" src="Images/logo.png" alt="Know Music">
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb1">Guitar</button>
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb2">Bass</button>
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb3">Piano</button>
        <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb4">Drums</button>
        <i class="fa fa-bars menu"></i>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="div-mi1">
        <img id="mi1" alt="Eletric Guitar" src="Images/guitarplaying.jpg">
        <h2 id="mt1" class="font">Test</h2>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If centering the div and its child elements is the only thing you're after, try adding `text-align: center;`to `#main { ... }`

```css
#main{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="heading">
    <img class="head" id="mainImg" src="Images/logo.png" alt="Know Music">
    <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb1">Guitar</button>
    <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb2">Bass</button>
    <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb3">Piano</button>
    <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb4">Drums</button>
    <i class="fa fa-bars menu"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="div-mi1">
    <img id="mi1" alt="Eletric Guitar" src="Images/guitarplaying.jpg">
    <h2 id="mt1" class="font">Test</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```